# How to get data from an array where length is not fixed

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having an array where length of the array is getting changes(may be increase/may be decrease) but minimum length is 1.
Key values are constant for each index of array like below

```
Myarr =  [ 
  {stdid:1, stddesc:"",coursedetails:"xyz"},
  {stdid:2, stddesc:"ccc",coursedetails:"abc"},.......
]
```

I want to fetch stdid for all the available index.

Can anyone help me here.

Comment: you need to loop it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ES6 map operator.

```js
Myarr = [{
  stdid: 1,
  stddesc: "",
  coursedetails: "xyz"
}, {
  stdid: 2,
  stddesc: "ccc",
  coursedetails: "abc"
}]
let idArr = Myarr.map(x => x.stdid);
console.log(idArr);
```

Comment: you changed the structure of input.

Comment: Yes, because the question has  also been changed.

Comment: Myarr.map(x => x.stdid); is working properly. Thanks a lot.